# Is it possible to implement multi-tenancy with Spring Data LDAP?

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-data, multi-tenant, spring-ldap

I am planning to use Spring Data LDAP to manage users in my Active Directory. But I have multiple OUs with same User Schema. Is it possible with Spring Data LDAP to achieve multi-tenancy to choose OUs based on the tenant context?

Comment: Keeping my requirement simple.-- I need to populate **base** dynamically based on the tenant context.

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve... base DN for the LDAP connection is kind of not that important thing when it comes to LDAP. AFAIK Spring LDAP itself is not using base DN in any way. Then you have base DN for search requests... that is specified with each request, so you can handle multi-tenancy yourself.

Comment: @PavelHoral Thanks for your quick response.